# Ruby on Rails + Postgres Migration removing enable_extension "pgcrypto" from schema.rb on every db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pgcrypto

This line is being removed from my schema.rb file every time I migrate;

`enable_extension "pgcrypto"`

... but I have no idea why!  No where am I dropping the extension and there is a migration that adds it very early in the stack of migrations (months ago).

This just started, and I have changed/updated nothing.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should have some migration in your code to enable the `pgcrypto` extension but for some reason, it might not be run on your system. Try to find migration file that has `enable_extension 'pgcrypto'` or a similar command and rerun it.

Comment: This helped me.. I created a new migration to readd it and it turned out my user had lost superadmin at some point and I was getting a C permission denied error so it was removing it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Sachin Singh's comment.  This helped me to figure it out.